# Don't use reputation loss from curation activities in Collectives Leaderboard

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-review, collectives

I have joined Mobile Development Collective to see what is the difference between being regular user and being member of a Collective in terms of actions I see and can do.

At the moment I am rarely answering in tags that belong to Mobile Development, but I am participating in curation. That includes downvoting bad posts even when it means losing some of my reputation.

But, that reputation loss can be seen on the Collective Leaderboard, and in my case it puts me at the very end with current reputation gain of -1.

It makes sense that you combine reputation gains and losses on the leaderboard on your own posts, but losses from downvoting bad posts should be excluded.

I personally don't care about my position on the Leaderboard, but if you want to attract people to  join the Collectives (I still haven't figured out what is the advantage, besides being listed as a member and put on the Leaderboard), maybe punishing those that are moderating the site is not the best idea.

Comment: I don't disagree, it's valid point. I'll bring this back to the team but it's likely to be a lower priority item right now.

Comment: @Carog Thanks! I understand this is not the top priority feature.